# Set child component property from parent before view rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to set child component property from its parent before its view rendered.

Now I use ViewChildren decorator in the parent component, but in this case is too late, because children view have to use the data which came from the parent.

So the grid class hold the full reference of the grid object, and I want to bind from grid-header to grid-header-item.

Root html:

```
<grid-header [grid]="grid" [ngClass.xs]="{'search-open': grid.searchToggle, 'mobile-header': true}">
    <grid-header-item fxFlex="75px" name="Level"></grid-header-item>
    <grid-header-item fxFlex name="Type"></grid-header-item>
    <grid-header-item fxFlex name="Stats"></grid-header-item>
</grid-header>
```

Parent component:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, forwardRef, Input, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { 
    StorageService, 
} from '../../_shared';

import { 
    GridHeaderItemComponent, 
} from './';

@Component({
    selector: 'grid-header',
    templateUrl: './grid-header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./grid-header.component.scss'],
    host: {'fxLayout': 'row'}
})
export class GridHeaderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    constructor(storage: StorageService) {}

    @Input() grid = null;
    @ViewChildren(forwardRef(() => GridHeaderItemComponent)) private headerItem;

    public ngOnInit() {

    }

    public ngAfterViewInit() {

        console.log(this.headerItem);

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.headerItem.grid = this.grid;
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

child component:

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { 
    StorageService, 
} from '../../_shared';

@Component({
    selector: 'grid-header-item',
    templateUrl: './grid-header-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./grid-header-item.component.scss'],
    host: {

    }
})
export class GridHeaderItemComponent implements OnInit {
    public grid;

    constructor(storage: StorageService) {}

    @Input() name: string = '';

    public ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
        // this.storage.unsubscribeAll(this.class);
    }
}
```

child componetn html:

```
<span class="item" (click)="grid.onSortBy(name);">
    {{name}} <span *ngIf="grid.sort == name" class="fa" [ngClass]="grid.getDirection(name)"></span>
</span>
```

I know, if I add [grid]="grid" to grid-header-item element it works, but I think this is an overhead, because all of grid-header children have to get this reference so this is redundant.

```
<grid-header [grid]="grid" [ngClass.xs]="{'search-open': grid.searchToggle, 'mobile-header': true}">
    <grid-header-item fxFlex="75px" [grid]="grid" name="Level"></grid-header-item>
    <grid-header-item fxFlex [grid]="grid" name="Type"></grid-header-item>
    <grid-header-item fxFlex [grid]="grid" name="Stats"></grid-header-item>
</grid-header>
```

Comment: How it's looks like? I haven't heard about how to inject parent to its, child.

Comment: Unfortunately the parent get the grid object via @input decorator, so when the child inject the parent as you show, the grid property is null.

Comment: @yurzui you are right, I found other solution with componentFactory, but your answer more closer to the question. Pls, send an asnwer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since angular2 has dependency injection system based on components tree we can simply inject parent component instance in child component:

**grid-header.component.ts**

```
export class GridHeaderItemComponent implements OnInit {
    public grid;
    @Input() name: string = '';

    constructor(private parent: GridHeaderComponent) { }
```

and then assign `parent.grid` property to local `grid` property within ngOnInit

**grid-header.component.ts**

```
 public ngOnInit() {
   this.grid = this.parent.grid;
 }
```

You can also see it in action in **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5bD0v7q7wzJIADTqP4fa?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

With this solution you will have access to the data in the ngAfterViewInit, but you won't have "circural dependecy" (parent-><-child). If you need more detailed communication try to use events, or a shared service.

**gridHeader.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'grid-header-item',
    template: `
        <span class="item" (click)="grid.onSortBy(name);">
            {{name}} <span *ngIf="grid.sort == name">Sortby</span>
        </span>
    `
})
export class GridHeaderItemComponent{
    @Input() name: string = '';
    public grid:any = {};
}

@Component({
    selector: 'grid-header',
    template:  `
    <grid-header-item fxFlex="75px" name="Level"></grid-header-item><br/>
    <grid-header-item fxFlex name="Type"></grid-header-item><br/>
    <grid-header-item fxFlex name="Stats"></grid-header-item>`
})
export class GridHeaderComponent implements AfterViewInit{   
  @ViewChildren(GridHeaderItemComponent) private headers:Array<headerItem>;   
  @Input() grid = {};
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.headers.forEach(h=>{//it can be a QueryList too
        h.grid=this.grid;
    });
}}
```

And in the grid's wrapper component, you have something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<grid-header [grid]="grid"></grid-header>`,
})
//...
```